# Máscara a inputs generados de manera dinámica en php

Tags: php, javascript, input

Tengo la siguiente función

```html
$("#price").on({
  "focus": function(event) {
    $(event.target).select();
  },
  "keyup": function(event) {
    $(event.target).val(function(index, value) {
      return value.replace(/\D/g, "")
        .replace(/([0-9])([0-9]{2})$/, '$1,$2')
        .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d)\.?)/g, ".");
    });
  }
});
```

Esta máscara se aplica tal a como necesito en el input #price de mi formulario, pero ahora estoy generando varios inputs por medio de un ciclo en php, los inputs generados tienen un id así:

```
<input type="text" id="price_'.$i.'">
```

Donde $i toma un valor distinto para cada input según se ejecuta el ciclo.

Puedo solicitar su apoyo para entender cómo logro con .find o del modo que crean mejor que la función de máscara aplique a cada input generado con php, independientemente del número de inputs que sean generados?

Gracias.

Comment: Tal vez usando una misma clase en todos los inputs (Ej.: `price-input`) puedas aplicarlo en todos usando `$('.price-input')`. También como buena práctica deberías introducir el código jQuery dentro de un `$(function() { //codigo });`

Answer (score 0):

*jQuery* funciona con una especie de expresiones regulares para acceder a elementos:

Encierra la expresión entre corchetes para indicar que vas a buscar elementos por algún atributo, por ejemplo: `[id='price_']`, lo que viene después del signo igual es el valor que debe tener el atributo.

Para este caso, necesitas especificar que el valor del atributo buscado no es un valor absoluto, sino que inicia con `price_`; basta con agregar un circunflejo `^` antes del signo igual, quedando así: `[id^='price_']`

```js
$("[id^='price_']").on({
  "focus": function(event) {
    $(event.target).select();
  },
  "keyup": function(event) {
    $(event.target).val(function(index, value) {
      return value.replace(/!\D/g, "")
        .replace(/([0-9])([0-9]{2})$/, '$1,$2')
        .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d)\.?)/g, ".");
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="price_1">
<input type="number" id="price_2">
<input type="number" id="price_3">
<input type="number" id="price_4">
```

Ahora solo falta afinar detalles de la función para que realice los remplazos correctamente.